# How I can compute normals in a tesellated terrain?

Tags: opengl, c++, procedural-generation, terrain-rendering, normals

I'm trying to generate a terrain using tessellation. I tesselate patches, so the amount of data passed to the GPU is `4 * numberOfPatch * numberOfPatch`.

My problem is that I want compute the normal for each vertex, but I don't know how do it. I have generated a heightmap using fractal noise, and I have used the Sobel filter to generate the normal map from that.

The final result seems incorrect:

[image: Terrain coloured by normals]
[image: More terrain coloured by normals]

The normal map will be read in the Tessellation Evaluation Shader (TES) and then passed to the Fragment Shader.

The code for the normal map generation is this:

```
void Terrain::ComputeNormalMap(float heightMap[MAP_RESOLUTION][MAP_RESOLUTION])
{
for (int i = 0; i < MAP_RESOLUTION; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < MAP_RESOLUTION; j++)
    {
        int upIndex = i - 1;
        int downIndex = i + 1;
        int rightIndex = j + 1;
        int leftIndex = j - 1;
        if (upIndex < 0)
        {
            upIndex %= MAP_RESOLUTION;
            while (upIndex < 0)
            {
                upIndex += MAP_RESOLUTION;
            }
        }

        if (downIndex >= MAP_RESOLUTION)
        {
            downIndex %= MAP_RESOLUTION;
            while (downIndex < 0)
            {
                downIndex += MAP_RESOLUTION;
            }
        }

        if(rightIndex >= MAP_RESOLUTION)
        {
            rightIndex %= MAP_RESOLUTION;
            while (rightIndex < 0)
            {
                rightIndex += MAP_RESOLUTION;
            }
        }

        if(leftIndex < 0)
        {
            leftIndex %= MAP_RESOLUTION;
            while (leftIndex < 0)
            {
                leftIndex += MAP_RESOLUTION;
            }
        }
        float t = heightMap[upIndex][j]; //TOP
        float tr = heightMap[upIndex][rightIndex]; //TOP-RIGHT
        float tl = heightMap[upIndex][leftIndex]; //TOP-LEFT
        float r = heightMap[i][rightIndex]; //RIGHT
        float l = heightMap[i][leftIndex]; //LEFT
        float b = heightMap[downIndex][j]; //BOTTOM
        float br = heightMap[downIndex][rightIndex]; //BOTTOM
        float bl = heightMap[downIndex][leftIndex]; //BOTTOM
        // sobel filter
        const float dX = (tr + 2.0f * r + br) - (tl + 2.0f * l + bl);
        const float dY = (bl + 2.0f * b + br) - (tl + 2.0f * t + tr);
        const float dZ = 1.0f/9.0f;

        glm::vec3 n(dX, dY, dZ);
        n = glm::normalize(n);
        NormalMap.emplace_back(n);
        
    }
 }

}
```

The code of TES is this:

```
// tessellation evaluation shader
#version 460 core

layout (quads, fractional_odd_spacing, ccw) in;

uniform sampler2D heightMap;  // the height map generated with fractal noise
uniform sampler2D normalMap;  
uniform mat4 model;           // the model matrix
uniform mat4 view;            // the view matrix
uniform mat4 proj;      // the projection matrix
uniform float heightScale;
uniform int teseNumberOfTile;
uniform float texelSize;

//received from Tessellation Control Shader - all texture coordinates for the patch 
vertices
in vec2 TextureCoord[];

out vec2 teseTexCoord;
out vec3 normalColor;


void main()
{
float Height;
// get patch coordinate
float u = gl_TessCoord.x;
float v = gl_TessCoord.y;

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// retrieve control point texture coordinates
vec2 t00 = TextureCoord[0];
vec2 t01 = TextureCoord[1];
vec2 t10 = TextureCoord[2];
vec2 t11 = TextureCoord[3];

// bilinearly interpolate texture coordinate across patch
vec2 t0 = (t01 - t00) * u + t00;
vec2 t1 = (t11 - t10) * u + t10;
vec2 texCoord = (t1 - t0) * v + t0;
teseTexCoord = texCoord;

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
float HeightValue = texture(heightMap, texCoord/200).x * heightScale;
if(HeightValue < 0)
{
    Height = HeightValue * heightScale / 2.3;
}
else
{
    Height = HeightValue * heightScale;
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// retrieve control point position coordinates
vec4 p00 = gl_in[0].gl_Position;
vec4 p01 = gl_in[1].gl_Position;
vec4 p10 = gl_in[2].gl_Position;
vec4 p11 = gl_in[3].gl_Position;

//I read the normalMap
normalColor = texture(normalMap, (texCoord/200)).rgb;
// bilinearly interpolate position coordinate across patch
vec4 p0 = (p01 - p00) * u + p00;
vec4 p1 = (p11 - p10) * u + p10;
vec4 p = (p1 - p0) * v + p0;
p.y = Height;


// output patch point position in clip space
gl_Position = proj * view * model * p;
}
```

Can someone tell me whether this is correct, and if not, how to fix it?

Comment: This question gives a few solutions for calculating normals
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/133864/calculating-vertex-normals-in-opengl-c I can tell your following the learnopengl.com tutorials so here is an article from that website on normals https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-Lighting/Normal-Mapping If you need anymore help tell me

Comment: Maybe the colour must be different... I don't know. Indeed the colour is similiar to a Normal Map. So maybe is correct

Comment: It sounds to me like you don't have any evidence that this is incorrect, you're just anxious that it might be. Try making a simple test with a directional light source - does the correct side of the hill light up? If not, that will give you concrete evidence you can use to describe the problem.

Comment: @DMGregory you got the point... I will follow your advice thanks so much.